# Kivy callback custom widget call from ids raise AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to call a custom widget method from its ids.

But I received an `AttributeError: 'LabelBox' object has no attribute 'change_first_text'`.

As a simple as possible working example can be found here with the PanelApp.py file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_file("panel.kv")

class LabelBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LabelBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def change_first_text(self, text):
        self.ids.first.text = text

class ButtonList(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.test = Test()
        self.btn_list = ButtonList()
        self.vbox = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.vbox.add_widget(self.btn_list)
        self.vbox.add_widget(self.test)
        return self.vbox

    def change_first(self, value):
        print("Button clicked and new value is: '{}'".format(value))
        self.test.ids.lbs.change_first_text(value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

and the panel.kv file:

```
<ButtonList@ButtonList>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    Button:
        text: "change fisrt to me"
        on_press: app.change_first(self.text)
    Button:
        text: "change two to me"

<LabelBox@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        id: first
        text: "first"
    Label:
        id: two
        text: "two"

<Test>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'first tab'
        LabelBox:
            id: lbs
```

Calling the script cause a runtime error that I can't understand.
Have you any clue on how to manage such event callback through the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your case is that you are creating 2 classes called `LabelBox`:

1.

```
class LabelBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LabelBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def change_first_text(self, text):
        self.ids.first.text = text
```

2.

```
<LabelBox@BoxLayout>:
    Label:
        id: first
        text: "first"
    Label:
        id: two
        text: "two"
```

I understand that you only want to have a class so it is appropriate to do the creation with the inheritance in the .py and only the implementation of children in the `.kv`. The solution is to change delete `@BoxLayout` in the `.kv`

```
<LabelBox>:
    Label:
        id: first
        text: "first"
    Label:
        id: two
        text: "two"
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works. I totally missed the "details" of `@BoxLayout` in the `.kv` file used to create a new class. Spent hours looking for this issue :-(